# Stored Procedure Executed through SQL server management studio but not through code

Tags: java, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a MS-SQL Server SP

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_OFFER_Existing_BFL_Result] ( @Name varchar(200), 
@mobile varchar(50), @city varchar(200), @partner_ref_no varchar(200), 
@partner_id varchar(50), @line_type varchar(50) )
AS 
BEGIN
INSERT INTO [NSB].[dbo].[Request] (Name,Mobile,City,Partner_Ref_No, 
Partner_ID, Line_Type, Enquiry_Request_Date)
VALUES(@Name, @mobile, @city, @partner_ref_no, @partner_id, @line_type, 
GETDATE())

IF exists (SELECT 1 FROM [ [NSB].[dbo].[NSB_CT_API_TEST] WHERE 
[Mobileno]=@mobile AND [PRODUCT_OFFERING_TYPE__C]=@line_type) 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [NSB].[dbo].[Response] ([Customer_Name], [Offer], 
[Offer_Amount], [Offer_Expiry_Date], [Offer_Type], [Mobile_No], 
[Response_Date_Time] )
    SELECT [Customer_NAME], [Offer_status], [AMOUNT_Offer], 
[Offer_Expiry_date], [PRODUCT_OFFERING_TYPE__C], [Mobileno], getdate() FROM 
[ [NSB].[dbo].[NSB_CT_API_TEST] WHERE Mobileno=@mobile AND 
[PRODUCT_OFFERING_TYPE__C]=@line_type

    BEGIN
        SELECT [Customer_NAME], [Offer_status], [AMOUNT_Offer], 
[Offer_Expiry_date], [PRODUCT_OFFERING_TYPE__C], [Mobileno] FROM [ [NSB].
[dbo].[NSB_CT_API_TEST] WHERE [Mobileno]=@mobile AND 
PRODUCT_OFFERING_TYPE__C=@line_type
    END
END 

ELSE
    SELECT 'Customer does not exists' AS ERROR 
END
```

When I am executing it through SQL Server Management Studio, it shows me a row of the data. But when I am calling this proc through my code, I am not getting any response.

Ideally, the second last select

```
BEGIN
        SELECT [Customer_NAME], [Offer_status], [AMOUNT_Offer], 
[Offer_Expiry_date], [PRODUCT_OFFERING_TYPE__C], [Mobileno] FROM [ [NSB].
[dbo].[NSB_CT_API_TEST] WHERE [Mobileno]=@mobile AND 
PRODUCT_OFFERING_TYPE__C=@line_type
END
```

This must be my output.

Java Code :

```
        logger.info("calling SP : SP_OFFER_Existing_BFL_Result ");
        statement = conn.prepareCall("{call 
SP_OFFER_Existing_BFL_Result(?,?,?,?,?,?)}");
        statement.setString(1, request.getName());
        statement.setString(2, request.getMobile());
        statement.setString(3, request.getCity());
        statement.setString(4, request.getRequestId());
        statement.setString(5, request.getPartnerid());
        statement.setString(6, request.getLinetype());
        logger.info("Stored Procedure called");
        logger.info("Stored Procedure called : " + statement);
        boolean isReturned = statement.execute();
        int updateCount = statement.getUpdateCount();
        logger.info("isReturned : " + isReturned);
        logger.info("update count : " + updateCount);
        boolean hasResults = false;

        hasResults = statement.getMoreResults();
        logger.info("Has Results : " + hasResults);

        if (hasResults) {
            logger.info("SP Returned Data");
            resultSet = statement.getResultSet();
        } else {
            logger.info("SP Returned No Data");
        }
```

Mentioning one more similar SP here, if I called this SP, I get the data from code as well.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_OFFER_TABLE](@INPUT_CUSTOMER_MOBILE VARCHAR(30)) 
AS 
IF exists (SELECT 1 FROM NSB.[dbo].[NSB_CT_API_TEST] WHERE 
Mobileno=@INPUT_CUSTOMER_MOBILE) 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Response] (Customer_name ,Offer ,Offer_Amount 
,Offer_Expiry_Date ,Offer_Type ,Mobile_No ,Created_Date )
    SELECT Customer_Name, Offer_status, AMOUNT_Offer, Offer_Expiry_date, 
PRODUCT_OFFERING_TYPE__C, Mobileno, GETDATE() AS Created_Date FROM NSB.
[dbo].[NSB_CT_API_TEST] WHERE Mobileno=@INPUT_CUSTOMER_MOBILE

    SELECT Customer_Name, Offer_status, AMOUNT_Offer, Offer_Expiry_date, 
PRODUCT_OFFERING_TYPE__C, Mobileno FROM NSB.[dbo].[NSB_CT_API_TEST] WHERE 
Mobileno=@INPUT_CUSTOMER_MOBILE 
END 
ELSE
SELECT 'Customer does not exists' AS ERROR
```

Can anybody help please.

Comment: what's your code?

Comment: Hi @Petaflop, I have updated the question with the code.

Comment: Use Sql Server Profiler to debug that problem